# Error return value in C++ does not match function type

Tags: c++, object

I have looked through many responses to others on here as well as YouTube videos to try to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a header file that defines a private class member as:

```
char *m_sName[64];
```

And public constructor destructor and an overloaded constructor.

And in my cpp file this:

```
Character::Character()
{
    *m_sName = NULL;
}

Character::Character(char *name, int cl, int al, int hp, int str, int dex, int con, int itl, int wis, int chr)
{
    *m_sName = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(*m_sName, name);
}

void Character::setName(char *name)
{
    *m_sName[] = (char *)malloc(strlen(name) + 1); // Error expected a
                                                   //expression
    strcpy(*m_sName, name);
}

void Character::getName(char *name)
{
    char *name = new char[strlen(*m_sName) + 1];
    strcpy(name, *m_sName);
    return name; // Error here return value type does not match function type
}

Character::~Character()
{
    delete [] *m_sName;
}
```

Now, I understand that sName is an array and the other is just a char. But even if I change it to a double I get the same problem. The other issue in setName I have no idea how to resolve it...

Comment: You are trying to return something in a function which has a return type of void. Delete the return statement.
Also, delete most of your code and use std::string and std::vector. You will run into much trouble if you continue like that. Finally, if you learn C++ by a tutorial or book where such code is presented, switch your literature. Nobody should write code like this any more.

Comment: Further question to you then because I'm obviously new, it's for an assignment and if his main doesn't work then I'll get a 0. will making those changes cause his to not work?

Comment: What do you mean by "his main"?

Comment: My professor has a main that he is going to use with our cpp and header files. so everything that is set like the private and public members can't change..

Comment: OK, so why are you asking us if we don't have the code and you do (and you can just try it)?

Comment: Because I haven't finished and I don't want to continue to do either way if it is wrong? I've been trying to work on this error for a long time now.

Comment: If `m_sName` is going to represent a name, it should be a `std::string` or, if you are not allowed to use them, a null terminated char array, that you can declare (if you know the max capacity, 63 chars) as `char m_sName[64];`. With `char *m_sName[64];` you are declaring an array of 64 pointers to char.

Comment: after rereading my question I realize I can't change it....

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you I didn't understand that.

Comment: Use std::string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. But if you just want to make it work, you can try this:

```
void Character::setName(char *name)
{
    delete [] *m_sName; // Avoid memory leak
    *m_sName = (char *)malloc(strlen(name) + 1); // delete `[]'
    strcpy(*m_sName, name);
}

char * Character::getName(char *name) // Change the return type
{
    char *name = new char[strlen(*m_sName) + 1];
    strcpy(name, *m_sName);
    return name;
}
```

Comment: It's not that I want it to just work... I want to do it in a way that makes sense. I just don't think I understand it enough to make the right choices. "A character array, called m_sName capable of holding up to 64 characters" A character array and std::string just aren't the same thing right?

Comment: a character array is `char tmp[64];`, not `char *tmp[64];`.  The latter is a pointer to a char array.

Comment: Right that I understand. So my instructions have char m_sName[64], and that there is this pointer char *name. The first is private and the second is public. *name is just supposed to be the pointer that points to m_sName right? So I removed all the '*' infront of m_sName (they weren't there to begin with I was just desperately trying anything I could reading other solutions I was finding) And now I encounter that M_sName has to be a modifiable value which I know it can't be because it's private right? That is the purpose of private and public or so I thought.

Comment: can you post the simplified class definition?

Comment: For just the section I am working on :  

class Character
{
 private:
  char m_sName[64];

 public:
  Character();
  Character(char *name, int cl, int al, int hp, int str, int dex, int con, int itl, int wis, int chr);
  ~Character();
  void getName(char *name);
  void setName(char *name);

}

Comment: m_sName is a member of the class so it is modifiable by the class other members even if it is private.